# React Router , pagination with query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-pagination

In my react app I have a component that requires pagination. What I would like to do, is to actually allow for pagination to be done also from the url, not only the ui. So if I go to

```
localhost\users?page=2
```

I could share the link to anyone and they will be redirected to page 2 of the users component.

Currently I'm doing something like this

```
<Pagination
  page={state.pageNo}
  count={state.pageCount}
  variant="outlined"
  shape="rounded"
  color="secondary"
  showLastButton={state.pageCount > 7}
  showFirstButton={state.pageCount > 7}
  hideNextButton={state.pageCount === 1}
  hidePrevButton={state.pageCount === 1}
  onChange={onPageChange}

  renderItem={pageItem => (
    <PaginationItem
      type={'start-ellipsis'}
      component={Link}
      selected
      to={`${pageItem.page}`}
      {...pageItem}
    />
  )}
/>
```

And my route template looks something like this

```
 { path: 'users/:id', element: <UsersList /> }
```

So I can actually go to  `localhost/users/2` but this is not the right url form that I want to use, this is linked this to a UserDetails component and it should stay this way.

I'm able to extract the query params from the URL, but don't know how to use them

```
const query = useQuery();
const { page } = queryString.parse(query);
```

where `useQuery` is a helper function wrapping `useLocation().search;`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `this.props.location.search` or `window.location.search` and `URLSearchParams` in your `Page Component`

Usage:

```
const page = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get("page")
```

OR

```
const page = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('page')
```

`page` variable you can pass to your `Pagination` component

```
// Example
componentDidUpdate() {
    const page = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get('page')
    // for example you are maintaining page inside state then
    this.setState({page})
}
```

Comment: yes, I'm over that part I just don't know how to use exactly

Comment: check answer now

Comment: What I want is to when selecting page=3, the URL to become `localhost\users?page=3' . and 2nd when I copy thist url and paste it in another browser or window, the result should be that of the page=3. I'm not sure how what you've added is going to help me ? I'm already doing that I can extract the query and pars it but this is where I don't know how to continue.

Comment: onPageChange write this function in your question